# Intermediate step in proving Cauchy's Integral Formula

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to understand the proof of the Cauchy's Integral Formula from the J. Conway, *Complex Integration* book. He states that

[image]

However, I don't know how to solve what he left as exercise 1, at the beginning of the proof. Can anyone give me a hint? Thanks

Comment: $z\neq w$ for all $z$. $f$ is analytic and $f(w)$ is a constant.

Comment: It is clear that $z \mapsto \phi(z,w)$ is analytic for $z \neq w$. Since $\phi$ is bounded in a neighbourhood of $w$ (since continuous), we see that $z \mapsto \phi(z,w)$ has a removable singularity at $z=w$ and hence is analytic (Riemann's theorem).

Answer (score 2):

All that is needed is to show that $g(z) = \phi(z,w)$ is continuously differentiable.

**Hint**: Note that we can write
$f(z) = \sum_{k \ge 0} a_k (z-w)^k$, and use this to obtain a formula
for $g(z)$.

Details:

> Since $f$ is analytic at $w$ we have some $R>0$ such that $B(w,R) \subset G$ and  $f(z) = \sum_{k \ge 0} a_k (z-w)^k$ for $z \in B(w,R)$,  where $a_k = {1 \over k!} f^{(k)}(w)$ (Theorem 2.8 in Chapter IV).

$ $

> Let $\gamma(z) = \sum_{k \ge 0} a_{k+1} (z-w)^{k}$, and note that $\gamma$ is analytic on $B(w,R)$.

$ $

> Note that $\gamma(w) = g(w) = f'(w)$, and $\gamma(z) = g(z)$ for $z \neq w$, hence $g=\gamma$ and so $g$ is continuously differentiable.